# Executing code from a chrome extension before the event $window.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute code from a chrome extension before the event $window.ready.

Apparently "runs_at": "document_start" should work, [according to Google](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

However, it doesn't seem to work. The following code :

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Testextension Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "file:///C:/test.html"
        ],
        "js": ["test.js"],
        "runs_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

test.js:

```
console.log("the extension content script is happening");
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    console.log ("script is happening in page");
    $(window).ready(function () {console.log("window.ready is happening");});
    $(document).ready(function () {console.log("document.ready is happening");});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

gives the following console output:

```
script is happening in page
window.ready is happening
document.ready is happening
the extension content script is happening
```

I don't own the page my extension should work on, so I can't modify it to execute after my Chrome extension.

Did I do anything wrong, or is this a problem with Chrome ?

What can I do ?

edit: is this about my use of "runs_at" instead of "run_at" ?

edit2: sorry it seems to be about that.

Comment: How to mark it as resolved ?

Comment: Thanks, but I will have to wait.

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 12/31/2013 5:44:14 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Please post your answer tomorrow, and accept it in the new year. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed because I made the spelling mistake "runs_at" (instead of "run_at"). My Chrome extension now works as intended.